# How does sorting a vector of references to references of str work on the strings rather than the outermost references?

Tags: sorting, rust, reference, vec

While learning `rust`, I ran across this snippet embedded within an answer to an online problem.  I didn't expect this to be the correct answer as I naively thought `elem_refs.sort()` would sort by the references in the vector rather than the strings.

Why does elem_refs.sort() sort on the strings rather the the references to the strings (or rather `&str`'s) ?  Obviously, it is convenient and the desired result but where is this behavior documented?  Much obliged for your insights.

```
fn main() {
    let list = ["b", "d" , "q", "a", "t" ];
    let mut elem_refs: Vec<&&str> = list.iter().collect();
    println!("{:?}", elem_refs);
    elem_refs.sort();
    println!("{:?}", elem_refs);
}
```

`["b", "d", "q", "a", "t"]`

`["a", "b", "d", "q", "t"]`

Comment: comparing reference that are not in the same allocation is UB in C. People must stop think reference/pointer is just a number, it's not. It's make no sense to sort a reference based on the value of the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, there are two answers to this question: the "philosophical", and the practical.

The "philosophical" answer, is that Rust prefers to deal with data, and not pointers.
Even if you have a reference to a value, it's often treated as just a handle to the value, and the fact that behind the scenes a reference is just a pointer, with a specific address in memory, is a detail that Rust prefers you not think about too much. (At least, this is my understanding of Rust philosophy. Feel free to correct me)
Even if you have two references, comparing them using `==` would compare them by-value (Due to a call to `PartialEq::eq`). If you really want to compare them by-reference, you would need to either convert them to pointers first, or call a function like `std::ptr::addr_eq`. (And to my understanding, even the idea of comparison by-reference is considered un-idiomatic in Rust)

Now the practical answer, is that the implementation of `sort` uses the `Ord` trait to decide the order of the elements in the sorted slice. ([look at the `where` clause on the signature of `sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort))
The `Ord` trait (and the related `PartialOrd` trait) exists for the purpose of deciding the order of types by-value, and indeed [the implementation of `Ord` for `str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.76.0/src/core/str/traits.rs.html#19) calls `self.as_bytes().cmp(other.as_bytes())` to compare the actual bytes contained in the strings.

Somewhat related to this, is the behaviour of the dot operator (`.`) in Rust, which is used to access the fields and methods of a type. Using the dot operator on a variable always implicitly dereferences that variable if it is a reference, before actually accessing the field/method.
It will even dereference it multiple times if it's a nested reference. This means that for any type `T` (even primitive types like `i32`), if you have a variable `let my_var: &&&T = ...`, and you do something like `my_var.some_field`, that would be equivalent to `(***my_var).some_field`.
This in turn means, that any method being called on a reference (like the methods from `Ord` that are called by the implementation of `sort`), will deal with the actual data inside the reference, and not the reference itself.

A disclaimer that I'd like to add is that I'm somewhat new to Rust, and so not everything I said might be 100% correct. I'm open to comments on this answer correcting me, so that I can edit this answer with the corrections.

Answer (score 3):

First, [`sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort) requires the trait [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html). `Ord` is implemented for references [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#impl-Ord-for-%26A), which dereferences the arguments and calls `Ord::cmp` again:

```rust
impl<A: ?Sized> Ord for &A
where
    A: Ord,
{
    #[inline]
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        Ord::cmp(*self, *other)
    }
}
```

When you call `sort`, the compiler looks for an implementation of `Ord` for `&&str`. It finds the generic one above, assigns `&str` to `A`, and then according to the bound `A: Ord`, looks for an implementation of `Ord` for `&str`. It finds the same one again, assigns `str` to `A`, and then looks for an implementation of `Ord` for `str`. It finds the specific implementation for `str` [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#impl-Ord-for-str), which ends the search. This chain of implementations is used to generate your specific `sort` function.

Comment: How does that implementation compile? It moves out of `&self` without `A` being `Copy`?

Comment: @BallpointBen On the second iteration, `A` is `str`, which means `Self` is `&str` (`for &A`), which means `self` is `&&str`. That gets dereferenced to `&str` which is `Copy`, since it is a reference.